# Is this map $\mathbf{Z}$-bilinear?

Tags: modules, group-rings, abstract-algebra

Let $M=\mathbf{Z}[C_n]$ have a $\mathbf{Z}$-basis $\{e^1,\ldots,e^{2n-1}\}$, then I want to show the following map is $\mathbf{Z}$-bilinear.
$\varphi:M\times M\to\mathbf{Z}$

$(e^r,e^s)\mapsto\begin{cases}1,&r={s+1}\\-1,&s=r+1\\0,&o/w\end{cases}\\$

Does anyone have any thoughts? I was thinking of breaking this up into two maps as follows:

$(e^r,e^s)\mapsto e^re^{-s}\mapsto\begin{cases}sgn(r-s)\\0\end{cases}$

The problem then arises about how to show linearity in the first variable. I get,

$(e^r+e^s,e^k)\mapsto e^{r-k}+e^{s-k}\mapsto ???$

What do I do next?

Comment: I think this is somewhat tautological - you're defining a bilinear form on a generating set of $M \times M$, and then implicitly extending this by $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinearity to a map on all of $M \times M$.

Comment: Perhaps I am overthinking the matter. But surely I have to show that the map I am defining is bilinear?

Comment: But since you have only defined the map on a generating set, the way you would evaluate $\varphi$ at some point of $M\times M$ is precisely by using the fact that it is bilinear (i.e. we extended it to all of $M \times M$ so that it is bilinear). For example, what is $\varphi(5e^1 + 2e^2, e^3 - 3e^4)$?

Comment: But I would have thought, I would still need to show somehow that I can extend it. Is it always a fact that we can extend a map which is defined on a basis to the whole module? I would have thought I needed to show that addition is preserved, for example, so that I can then extend it to the whole of $M\times M$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - but what addition are you preserving? I would have thought you meant that $\varphi(e^1 + 2e^3, e^5) = \varphi(e^1,e^5) + 2\varphi(e^3,e^5)$, for example.

Comment: Well I meant, I would have thought I had to actually show $\varphi(e^r+e^s)=\varphi(e^r)+\varphi(e^s)$ so that I could then extend to the whole of $M\times M$.

Comment: Otherwise I am defining a map on basis elements, and then extending it to the whole of $M\times M$ without actually demonstrating that my map is in any way bilinear.

Comment: Ah I see your point, I had forgotten that we had addition in $C_n$ to work with: in this case, you're right, we do need to show bilinearity. Apologies for any confusion!

Comment: That's alright. I was beginning to doubt whether I was massively overthinking the problem. In which case I seem to be stuck.